# installing stringr, stringi "Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringi’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)" and shared object issue

Tags: r, installation, knitr, stringr, stringi

I am using Fedora 32, compiled from source the latest R  4.0.2 (the problem persists even under another clean install of 3.6.3).

I got this error

```
> install.packages("stringi")
Installing package into ‘/home/andrespara/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
probando la URL 'https://espejito.fder.edu.uy/cran/src/contrib/stringi_1.4.6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 7284354 bytes (6.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 6.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘stringi’ ...
** package ‘stringi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for R_HOME... /home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R
checking for R... /home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/bin/R
checking for endianness... little
checking for R >= 3.1.0 for C++11 use... yes
checking for R < 3.4.0 for CXX1X flag use... no
checking for cat... /usr/bin/cat
checking for local ICUDT_DIR... icu61/data
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking elf.h usability... yes
checking elf.h presence... yes
checking for elf.h... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... yes
checking whether the C++ compiler supports the long long type... yes
checking whether the compiler implements namespaces... yes
checking whether the compiler supports Standard Template Library... yes
checking whether std::map is available... yes
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking with pkg-config for the system ICU4C... 65.1
checking for ICU4C >= 55... yes
checking for additional required CPPFLAGS, LDFLAGS, and LIBS... done
checking whether we may build an ICU4C-based project... yes
checking programmatically for sufficient U_ICU_VERSION_MAJOR_NUM... yes
checking programmatically if U_CHARSET_IS_UTF8 is defined and set... yes
checking for available ICU data library (ucnv, uloc, utrans)... yes
checking for available ICU data library (ucol)... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
config.status: creating src/uconfig_local.h
config.status: creating src/install.libs.R

*** stringi configure summary:
    ICU_FOUND=1
    STRINGI_CXXSTD=CXX_STD=CXX11
    STRINGI_CFLAGS=   -fpic
    STRINGI_CPPFLAGS=-I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H
    STRINGI_CXXFLAGS=   -fpic
    STRINGI_LDFLAGS=-L/usr/lib64   
    STRINGI_LIBS=-licui18n -licuuc -licudata   

*** compiler settings used:
    CC=gcc
    LD=g++ -std=gnu++11
    CFLAGS=-g -O2 -fpic  
    CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include   -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG
    CXX=g++ -std=gnu++11
    CXXFLAGS=-g -O2 -fpic  
    LDFLAGS=  
    LIBS=  

** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_brkiter.cpp -o stri_brkiter.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_collator.cpp -o stri_collator.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_common.cpp -o stri_common.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_compare.cpp -o stri_compare.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_container_base.cpp -o stri_container_base.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_container_bytesearch.cpp -o stri_container_bytesearch.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_container_listint.cpp -o stri_container_listint.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_container_listraw.cpp -o stri_container_listraw.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_container_listutf8.cpp -o stri_container_listutf8.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_container_regex.cpp -o stri_container_regex.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_container_usearch.cpp -o stri_container_usearch.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_container_utf16.cpp -o stri_container_utf16.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_container_utf8.cpp -o stri_container_utf8.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_container_utf8_indexable.cpp -o stri_container_utf8_indexable.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_encoding_conversion.cpp -o stri_encoding_conversion.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_encoding_detection.cpp -o stri_encoding_detection.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_encoding_management.cpp -o stri_encoding_management.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_escape.cpp -o stri_escape.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_exception.cpp -o stri_exception.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_ICU_settings.cpp -o stri_ICU_settings.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_join.cpp -o stri_join.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_length.cpp -o stri_length.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_pad.cpp -o stri_pad.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_prepare_arg.cpp -o stri_prepare_arg.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_random.cpp -o stri_random.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_reverse.cpp -o stri_reverse.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_class_count.cpp -o stri_search_class_count.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_class_detect.cpp -o stri_search_class_detect.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_class_extract.cpp -o stri_search_class_extract.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_class_locate.cpp -o stri_search_class_locate.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_class_replace.cpp -o stri_search_class_replace.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_class_split.cpp -o stri_search_class_split.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_class_startsendswith.cpp -o stri_search_class_startsendswith.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_class_subset.cpp -o stri_search_class_subset.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_class_trim.cpp -o stri_search_class_trim.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_common.cpp -o stri_search_common.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_coll_count.cpp -o stri_search_coll_count.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_coll_detect.cpp -o stri_search_coll_detect.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_coll_extract.cpp -o stri_search_coll_extract.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_coll_locate.cpp -o stri_search_coll_locate.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_coll_replace.cpp -o stri_search_coll_replace.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_coll_split.cpp -o stri_search_coll_split.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_coll_startsendswith.cpp -o stri_search_coll_startsendswith.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_coll_subset.cpp -o stri_search_coll_subset.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_boundaries_count.cpp -o stri_search_boundaries_count.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_boundaries_extract.cpp -o stri_search_boundaries_extract.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_boundaries_locate.cpp -o stri_search_boundaries_locate.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_boundaries_split.cpp -o stri_search_boundaries_split.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_fixed_count.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_count.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_fixed_detect.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_detect.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_fixed_extract.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_extract.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_fixed_locate.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_locate.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_fixed_replace.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_replace.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_fixed_split.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_split.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_fixed_subset.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_subset.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_fixed_startsendswith.cpp -o stri_search_fixed_startsendswith.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_in.cpp -o stri_search_in.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_other_split.cpp -o stri_search_other_split.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_regex_count.cpp -o stri_search_regex_count.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_regex_detect.cpp -o stri_search_regex_detect.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_regex_extract.cpp -o stri_search_regex_extract.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_regex_locate.cpp -o stri_search_regex_locate.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_regex_match.cpp -o stri_search_regex_match.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_regex_replace.cpp -o stri_search_regex_replace.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_regex_split.cpp -o stri_search_regex_split.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_search_regex_subset.cpp -o stri_search_regex_subset.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_sort.cpp -o stri_sort.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_stats.cpp -o stri_stats.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_stringi.cpp -o stri_stringi.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_sub.cpp -o stri_sub.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_test.cpp -o stri_test.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_time_zone.cpp -o stri_time_zone.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_time_calendar.cpp -o stri_time_calendar.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_time_symbols.cpp -o stri_time_symbols.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_time_format.cpp -o stri_time_format.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_trans_casemap.cpp -o stri_trans_casemap.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_trans_other.cpp -o stri_trans_other.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_trans_normalization.cpp -o stri_trans_normalization.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_trans_transliterate.cpp -o stri_trans_transliterate.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_ucnv.cpp -o stri_ucnv.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_uloc.cpp -o stri_uloc.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_utils.cpp -o stri_utils.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -I.    -UDEBUG -DNDEBUG -DU_HAVE_ELF_H  -I/usr/local/include  -fpic -fpic  -g -O2  -c stri_wrap.cpp -o stri_wrap.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/lib -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath,/home/andrespara/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/andrespara/anaconda3/lib -L/home/andrespara/anaconda3/lib -o stringi.so stri_brkiter.o stri_collator.o stri_common.o stri_compare.o stri_container_base.o stri_container_bytesearch.o stri_container_listint.o stri_container_listraw.o stri_container_listutf8.o stri_container_regex.o stri_container_usearch.o stri_container_utf16.o stri_container_utf8.o stri_container_utf8_indexable.o stri_encoding_conversion.o stri_encoding_detection.o stri_encoding_management.o stri_escape.o stri_exception.o stri_ICU_settings.o stri_join.o stri_length.o stri_pad.o stri_prepare_arg.o stri_random.o stri_reverse.o stri_search_class_count.o stri_search_class_detect.o stri_search_class_extract.o stri_search_class_locate.o stri_search_class_replace.o stri_search_class_split.o stri_search_class_startsendswith.o stri_search_class_subset.o stri_search_class_trim.o stri_search_common.o stri_search_coll_count.o stri_search_coll_detect.o stri_search_coll_extract.o stri_search_coll_locate.o stri_search_coll_replace.o stri_search_coll_split.o stri_search_coll_startsendswith.o stri_search_coll_subset.o stri_search_boundaries_count.o stri_search_boundaries_extract.o stri_search_boundaries_locate.o stri_search_boundaries_split.o stri_search_fixed_count.o stri_search_fixed_detect.o stri_search_fixed_extract.o stri_search_fixed_locate.o stri_search_fixed_replace.o stri_search_fixed_split.o stri_search_fixed_subset.o stri_search_fixed_startsendswith.o stri_search_in.o stri_search_other_split.o stri_search_regex_count.o stri_search_regex_detect.o stri_search_regex_extract.o stri_search_regex_locate.o stri_search_regex_match.o stri_search_regex_replace.o stri_search_regex_split.o stri_search_regex_subset.o stri_sort.o stri_stats.o stri_stringi.o stri_sub.o stri_test.o stri_time_zone.o stri_time_calendar.o stri_time_symbols.o stri_time_format.o stri_trans_casemap.o stri_trans_other.o stri_trans_normalization.o stri_trans_transliterate.o stri_ucnv.o stri_uloc.o stri_utils.o stri_wrap.o -L/usr/lib64 -licui18n -licuuc -licudata -L/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/lib -lR
installing via 'install.libs.R' to /home/andrespara/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-stringi/00new/stringi
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
**Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringi’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/andrespara/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-stringi/00new/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
  /home/andrespara/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-stringi/00new/stringi/libs/stringi.so: undefined symbol: _ZTIN6icu_658ByteSinkE**
Error: loading failed
Ejecución interrumpida
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/andrespara/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/stringi’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpFZLEiI/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("stringi") :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
```

All the errors installing packages are similar to these lines

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stringi’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
unable to load shared object '/home/andrespara/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK- 
stringi/00new/stringi/libs/stringi.so':
/home/andrespara/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/00LOCK-stringi/00new/stringi/libs/stringi.so: 
undefined symbol: _ZTIN6icu_658ByteSinkE
```

This is my `sessionInfo()` result

```
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Generic 32 (Generic)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/libopenblas-r0.3.9.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=es_UY.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_UY.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=es_UY.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_UY.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=es_UY.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_UY.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_UY.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.2 tools_4.0.2    tcltk_4.0.2
```

I tried several solutions, I can't install devtools, I tried installing via remotes, these options `install.packages("Rcpp", dependencies = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock')` and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56889914/2187956)
The libraries are in

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/andrespara/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0"
[2] "/home/andrespara/4.0.2/lib64/R/library"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved this by using and old response combined with another arguments,

> install.packages("stringr_1.4.0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source", dependencies = TRUE, INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock', configure.args='--disable-pkg-config')

After I posted this question I was about to close a tab with a similar post and find this old answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39411793/2187956 suggesting the flag **--disable-pkg-config**